# My custom middleware is repeated several times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, middleware

I have used the following code in the middleware to store the number of visits (according to IP):

First, I check if the user is new or new by getting the user's IP, and then I check if the user has visited in the current day or not.
And if the current user is a new user, his IP will be recorded, otherwise, only the visit time will be recorded.

**this my middleware:**

```
public class VisitorCounter
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _requestDelegate;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public VisitorCounter(RequestDelegate requestDelegate, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _requestDelegate = requestDelegate;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ApplicationDbContext dBcontext)
    {
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("Matin.UserGuid", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        string ip = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        if (ip.Equals("::1"))
        {
            ip = "127.0.0.1";
        }
        if (await dBcontext.Database.CanConnectAsync())
        {
            if (await dBcontext.SY_Visits.AnyAsync())
            {
                try
                {
                    SY_Visit isToday = await dBcontext.SY_Visits.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.VisitDate.Equals(DateTime.Today));
                    if (isToday != null)
                    {
                        SY_Visit isIP = await dBcontext.SY_Visits.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.VisitIp.Equals(ip));
                        if (isIP != null)
                        {
                            dBcontext.Add(new SY_Visit
                            {
                                VisitIp = "",
                                VisitDate = DateTime.Today,
                                VisitTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
                            });
                            await dBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dBcontext.Add(new SY_Visit
                            {
                                VisitIp = ip,
                                VisitDate = DateTime.Today,
                                VisitTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
                            });
                            await dBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dBcontext.Add(new SY_Visit
                        {
                            VisitIp = ip,
                            VisitDate = DateTime.Today,
                            VisitTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
                        });
                        await dBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    await dBcontext.DisposeAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    dBcontext.Add(new SY_Visit
                    {
                        VisitIp = ip,
                        VisitDate = DateTime.Today,
                        VisitTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
                    });
                    await dBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    await dBcontext.DisposeAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        await _requestDelegate(context);
    }
}
```

and this startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {              
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseMiddleware<VisitorCounter>(); // this middleware
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "areas",
               pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapHub<OnlineUsersHub>("/onlineUsersHub");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               "error",
               "error/{statusCode}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Errors" });
        });
    }
```

But every time the pages are loaded (each page of the site), more than **4** to **20** records are stored in the database!!!
what is the problem? And how to solve it?
**thank you**

Comment: how do you add the middleware? please show the code

Comment: I would say that there is not enough information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Also note that it can be a questionable approach to dispose dependencies passed from outside.

Comment: Have you checked that you do indeed receive one and only one request during a page load? I imagine there's probably a request to `/favicon.ico` and seemingly others too when the browser loads the whole page apart from the main page request.

Comment: If you add your middleware to run before static files, then loading JavaScript, images, CSS etc will each count as a separate visit. The order you add your middleware is important.

Comment: i change position after app.UseStaticFiles(); but not fix

Comment: Each time you send a request,the middleware will be invoked.When debugging,how many times the middleware is invoked when you load the pages?